# Mounting Linux filesystem

Tags: finder, unix, filesystem, mount

I would like to read from an SD card containing the filesystem and OS from a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian / noobs.  [I have installed ext2fuse](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=328) (on Mac El Capitan 10.11.6):

```
$ brew update
$ brew tap caskroom/cask
$ brew cask install osxfuse
$ sudo shutdown -r now
$ brew install ext2fuse
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

Now when I put in an SD card (with Raspbian linux OS on it) I get the following:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_16 RECOVERY                1.2 GB     disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         33.6 MB    disk2s5
   3:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    66.1 MB    disk2s6
   4:                      Linux                         6.8 GB     disk2s7
```

But calling the following results in an empty directory being mounted:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/opt/ext2fuse/bin/ext2fuse /dev/disk2s7 /sd
$ cd /sd
$ ls
.
$ sudo /usr/local/opt/ext2fuse/bin/ext2fuse /dev/disk2 /sd2
/dev/disk2 is to be mounted at /sd2
fuse-ext2fs: Resource busy while trying to open /dev/disk2
```

Additionally I can't figure out how to unmount them.  Previously I used "eject all" option from clicking the eject icon next to the "boot" or "RECOVERY" mounted partitions in finder.  Calling the following doesn't work:

```
$ diskutil unmount /sd
(null) was already unmounted
$ sudo umount /sd
umount(/sd): Resource busy -- try 'diskutil unmount'
$ rmdir /sd
rmdir: sd: Resource busy
$ sudo mkdir /sd
mkdir: /sd: File exists
$ diskutil umount force /sd
Unmount failed for /sd
```

** **edit** **
Don't know what I did but I can now `sudo rmdir /sd` and they are removed.

Comment: Could you try `sudo mkdir /sd`, `sudo /usr/local/opt/ext2fuse/bin/ext2fuse /dev/disk2s7 /sd` and `diskutil umount force /sd` and report back the results?

Comment: do you want read/write into ext2/3 file system?

Comment: @jorvi haven't got sd card on me at the moment but `sudo mkdir /sd` => `mkdir: /sd: File exists`  and  `diskutil umount force /sd` => `Unmount failed for /sd`.

Comment: Just read ext2/3 file system would be great (though obviously write would be bonus but can't even get read working at the moment) @Sairam

Comment: @AJP, it would have been useful to know the problem you are solving in case the steps you were following were obsolete. Looks like there is an answer present now.

Comment: @Sairam yes good point.  Thank you.  I have edited the question in hindsight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove ext2fuse with `brew uninstall ext2fuse`.
- Download [fuse-ext2](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2) available at the git homepage and unzip it in your Downloads folder
- Follow these instructions:

  ```
  brew install m4
  brew install e2fsprogs automake autoconf libtool
  cd ~/Downloads/fuse-ext2-master
  ./autogen.sh
  CFLAGS="-idirafter/$(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/include -idirafter/usr/local/include/osxfuse" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/lib" ./configure
  make 
  sudo make install
  ```
- Mount the partition(s) e.g. disk2s7:

  ```
  sudo fuse-ext2 /dev/disk2s7 /sd -o allow_other,force,rw+
  ```

---

Tested & verified in a virtual 10.11.6 El Capitan machine!

Comment: Would have preferred using brew but will give this a go when get back onto Wifi.

Comment: This works well.  Do you know how you unmount too? (and bonus thanks for figuring out how to unmount the other drives)

Comment: With fuse-ext2 installed I always unmounted the volume by using the context menu > eject "Vol name". `sudo umount diskXsY` also works (with the proper X and Y). What do you mean with the "other" drives?

Comment: `ls /sd*` => `/sd: \n\n/sd2: \n\n/sd3: \n\n/sd4: \n` (others are from previous attempts)  and  `diskutil umount force /sd` => `Unmount failed for /sd`.  And restarting does not do anything, they're there when I come back.  (Also re bounty I have awarded to you in case it expires and I'd have to reissue.  Not sure how it works, don't want you to lose out after your excellent advice so far.  Thanks.)

Comment: @AJP You can unmount the mount point (/sd*)!. You should be able to get the mount point(s) and the volume name by entering `mount` and then unmount the volumes with `sudo umount [force] /mountpoint/vol_name`(e.g. `sudo umount /Volumes/SDData`

Comment: `mount` returned no results.  `sudo rmdir /sd` now works fine...?  Don't know what I did differently but it works (perhaps the restart did it).  Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @klanomath I used `FUSE for macOS` and `fuse-ext2` which are still in my `Preferences` but I had pretty much given up on `ext4` support under SIP. Could you expand your answer to include links to the code. I have never used `brew`; it it possible to use without (I have XCode complier).

Comment: @Milliways Link to which code? brew?

Comment: @klanomath I was referring to the git homepage, but I now see there is a link. My apologies. (My eyesight isn't too good lately.)

Comment: You can do this through brew now, see my comment here https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2/issues/81#issuecomment-482377219