# Ext4fuse usage to see and browse the volume in Finder

Tags: finder, mount, ext4

I want to copy some files of my old encrypted SSD with ubuntu.

I installed ext4fuse and done `sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk3s1  /Volumes/Linux`, although I don't know if it is the right partition number (where can I see them in Disk Utility?).

**How do I open then the disk in Finder?** Possibly in the "devices" section. I navigated to `/Volumes` and didn't see Linux (or whatever it is).

```
MacBook-Pro:Volumes mbp$ ls
Linux       Linux2      MacintoshHD
MacBook-Pro:Volumes mbp$ ls -la
ls: Linux: No such file or directory
ls: Linux2: No such file or directory
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@  5 root  wheel   170 Jul  4 15:38 .
drwxr-xr-x  29 root  wheel  1054 Jun 22 05:43 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1 Jun 22 06:01 MacintoshHD -> /
```

Comment: [Mounting linux filesystem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/286134/93229)

Answer (score 1):

add `-o allow_other` to `sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk3s1  /Volumes/Linux -o allow_other`. Source: https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/36#issuecomment-237390665